# Same SessionBeans with different states

Tags: java, jsf, session-bean

I have an issue that makes me think that i'm doing something in the wrong way.
I have a `sessionBean` with an entity called `CashRegister` that holds the cash register. When this property is `null`, then it means that no cash register has been created.

I have an action in a viewScope bean that in the method `GoToOrdersQueue` checks if the cash register (obtained from the session bean) is not `null` and then redirect to certain page... if the cash register is `null`, it shows a message saying that the cash register must be created first.

In the other hand, I have a `customFilter` (implementing `javax.servlet.Filter`) thats checks if the cash register of the session bean is not `null`, allowing to continue to the redirected page, and if the cash register is `null`, then redirects to a page that says: `"Cannot see the page because the Cash register must be created first"`

Know, my problem is that I create the cash register, then I call the method `GoToOrdersQueue` of the `viewScoped` bean and when it checks if the cash register is not `null`, the result is correct...not `null` so it redirect to the desired page, **but**.. when the filter is invoked to check if the cash register is not `null`, the result is incorrect ! because the session bean has the property `cash register` with `null` !

Is it the way I invoke the session bean the problem ?

In the method `GoToOrdersQueue` of the `viewScoped` bean i invoke the sessionbean like this:

```
ControllerSession sessionbean = JsfUtil.findBean("controllerSession");
```

where the method `findBean` is declared like this:

```
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
}
```

And in the filter I invoke the `sessionbean` like this:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
ControllerSession sessionbean = (ControllerSession) session.getAttribute("controllerSession");
```

Why they have differents states (in that particular property) if they are suppose to be the same object ? I use other properties like the logued user and works fine everytime.

thanks in advance for any tip !

by the way i'm using tomcat 7.0.40, jsf 2.2 and primefaces 3.5, but i think has nothing to do with this.

Comment: what is the scope of `controllerSession` ? Are you sure that you set the bean into session correctly?

Comment: yes yes, it is sessionscoped, I use it to save the 'logued user', and other things that belongs to the user session.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... In the ViewScoped bean, I was getting the instance of the sessionbean at the constructor, like this:

```
public ControllerViewScoped(){
    sessionbean = JsfUtil.findBean("controllerSession");
}
```

Well, don't know why but if I use that code in every method that use the sesisoncontroller, it works...

Thanks